# Google Sheets, How does one automatically sort Rows based on a columns data validation

Tags: google-sheets

The idea is there would be several ranks (think military)
And it would go;
General
Vice General
Commmander
Vice Commander
CPL
LCPL
etc...

This would all be able to be inputted via data validation and then the sheet would sort the entire row based on the rank column.

I'd very much appreciate any and all answers as I am completely unfamiliar with how google sheets work.
(I'm pretty sure it requires a script but hopefully not)

Comment: The basic idea would be to separate data entry from data presentation. On one worksheet the data would be entered, in the order that is most natural for data entry, and the other would present a sorted list, updated immediately after each entry, based on the first one.